# Repetir o valor de uma linha nas linhas imediatamente abaixo de uma dataframe no R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Preciso escrever uma função para que os valores destacados em amarelo sejam repetidos nas células abaixo, inclusive sobrescrevendo aquelas células que já possuem valores. De outra maneira, os valores a esquerda dos campos C100 (em vermelho) precisam ser replicados nas células a esquerda dos campos C170 e C190. O problema é que o número de vezes que esses valores deverão ser repetidos é variável, ou seja, eu tenho que repetir esses valores nas células abaixo até surgir o próximo C100 quando eles devem começar a receber as informações desse último C100 e assim por diante. Os dados abaixo para quem puder dar uma ajuda. Valeu!

```
COD_PART    COD_MOD SER NUM_DOC C1
3070        55      1   94      C100
        30      287,25  0       C170
        30      161,22  0       C170
        15      116,05  0       C170
        7       54,16   0       C170
        8       61,89   0       C170
        5       31,37   0       C170
        15      80,6    0       C170
        5       31,37   0       C170
        7       54,16   0       C170
        10      75,56   0       C170
        8       61,89   0       C170
        5       36,49   0       C170
        8       61,89   0       C170
        7       54,16   0       C170
0       1168,06     0   0       C190
3104        55      1   288     C100
        10      42,41   0       C170
        10      42,41   0       C170
0       84,82       0   0       C190
3104        55      1   295     C100
        10      34,16   0       C170
        15      63,62   0       C170
        15      63,62   0       C170
        10      41,61   0       C170
        5       15,51   0       C170
0       218,52      0   0       C190
2463        55      1   369     C100
        8       170,94  0       C170
0       170,94      0   0       C190
2463        55      1   380     C100
        10      213,68  0       C170
0       213,68      0   0       C190
2463        55      1   391     C100
        10      213,68  0       C170
        10      82,36   0       C170
        10      85  0       C170
0       85      0   0       C190
0       296,04      0   0       C190
2463        55      1   399     C100
        10      213,68  0       C170
        10      82,36   0       C170
0       296,04      0   0       C190
3075        55      1   544     C100
        1       118,83  0       C170
        1       94,71   0       C170
        6       47,7    0       C170
        12      95,4    0       C170
        6       52,38   0       C170
1,25        409,02      5,11    0       C190
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, considere sempre colocar um exemplo reproduzível e uma pergunta clara e objetiva do seu problema, [leia isto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seguinte código em R base resolve o problema.

```
f <- cumsum(!is.na(dados$COD_PART))
dados$COD_PART <- ave(dados$COD_PART, f, FUN = function(x){x[-1] <- x[1]; x})
```